# message: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-8, angular11

So I have an API route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function() {
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'seminar'], function() {
    Route::get('/{employee_number}', [UserProfileController::class, 'getSeminar']);
    Route::post('/{user}', [UserProfileController::class, 'createSeminar']);
    Route::put('/{seminar}', [UserProfileController::class, 'updateSeminar']);
    Route::delete ('/{seminar}', [UserProfileController::class, 'deleteSeminar']);
  });
});
```

And a controller

```
public function createSeminar(User $user, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->allowIfRecordOwner($user->id, function() use ($user, $request) {

            $seminar = Seminar::create([
                "user_id"           => $user->id,
                "dates"             => $request->dates,
                "name"              => $request->name,
                "certificate_number" => $request->certificate_number
            ]);
            return response()->json($seminar->toArray(), 200);
        });
    }
```

And im using that from my angular app

```
 private saveSeminar(index) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const seminar = this.userSeminars[index];
    if (seminar.id) {
      this.updateUserSeminar(index);
    } else {
      this.storeStudentAddress(index);
    }

  }

  private storeStudentAddress(index) {
    this.apiService.create('users/seminar', this.userSeminars[index])
    .subscribe(
    response => {
        this.userSeminars[index].edit = false;
        this.userSeminars[index].id = response.id;
        this.getUserSeminar(index.employee_number);
        this.toastr.success('Seminar Successfully saved', 'Success');
    });
  }
```

I have done `php artisan route:list` and found my router here

[image]

And I have now been staring at the error for over three hours and can't see why I'm getting the error. Any help would be wonderful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API endpoint in Laravel doesn't look like it lines up with your API endpoint in your JavaScript.

You need to hit this endpoint in order to create a seminar: `api/users/seminar/{user}`, where `{user}` is the user's ID.

Your line here: `this.apiService.create('users/seminar', this.userSeminars[index])` looks like it's instead hitting `api/users/seminar`, without the user's ID appended to the end.

You just need to change it to `this.apiService.create('users/seminar/' + USER_ID, ...` where `USER_ID` is whatever variable you're using to store the user's ID, or alternatively a method which returns it.

Comment: Yes you're right i've change the code as you've suggested. It nows gives me error 500 not 405.

Comment: That's a different question. Look at your Laravel logs, try to debug it yourself, if you can't then write a new question here on SO

Comment: ok thanks. i'll vote this as correct.